# issue with couldnt find fi to match an if in my edit of parrot-install script

Tags: shell

I'm having a hard time understanding where to put the corresponding 'fi' to match this 'if' in the last few lines of the **parrot-install.sh** script from the alternate-install.

Here are the errors shellcheck gives:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 138:
if [ `whoami` == "root" ]; then
^-- SC1046: Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'.
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this if expression. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 140:
done
^-- SC1047: Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'.
    ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

I haven't figured out the correct way to paste the code to get your site to let me post the question but my issues are the line 138 an 140 of the parrot-install.sh in the alternate-install github repo.

https://github.com/ParrotSec/alternate-install/blob/master/parrot-install.sh

I've added my own corrections using shellcheck an everything seems fine but those two lines of code I really would love to be able to contribute just a. don't really know how and wanna seem dumb/noob.B.To not be able to make a comment or know what a pull request is but I've never been more passionate about something in my life but programming an to be able to help out in any way would help me feel apart of something  sorry I posted a link but as i said I'm a noob and I can't understand the indentations to allow me to post the code here that's why the link is provided.

This is the output on shellcheck with original code as is on the link

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 4:
    NORMAL=`echo "\033[m"`
           ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
           ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    NORMAL=$(echo "\033[m")

Line 5:
    MENU=`echo "\033[36m"` #Blue
         ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
         ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    MENU=$(echo "\033[36m") #Blue

Line 6:
    NUMBER=`echo "\033[33m"` #yellow
           ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
           ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    NUMBER=$(echo "\033[33m") #yellow

Line 7:
    FGRED=`echo "\033[41m"`
    ^-- SC2034: FGRED appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
          ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
          ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    FGRED=$(echo "\033[41m")

Line 8:
    RED_TEXT=`echo "\033[31m"`
             ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
             ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    RED_TEXT=$(echo "\033[31m")

Line 9:
    ENTER_LINE=`echo "\033[33m"`
               ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
               ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
    ENTER_LINE=$(echo "\033[33m")

Line 21:
    read opt
    ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 27:
    MESSAGE=${@:-"${RESET}Error: No message passed"}
            ^-- SC2124: Assigning an array to a string! Assign as array, or use * instead of @ to concatenate.

Line 70:
while [ opt != '' ]
            ^-- SC2050: This expression is constant. Did you forget the $ on a variable?

Line 126:
        \n)exit;
        ^-- SC1012: \n is just literal 'n' here. For line feed, use a quoted, literal line feed instead.

Line 138:
if [ `whoami` == "root" ]; then
     ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
     ^-- SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2006)
if [ $(whoami) == "root" ]; then
```

Comment: The code in the link doesn't produce that warning; did you run `shellcheck` on your modified version?

Comment: yes I've managed to get it down to only two errors.But I'm a lil sleep deprived an I'm completely uneducated at this,I can't understand basic HTML an I'm trying to revamp the alternate-install /parrot-install.sh from 2013, I think was the year. Anyway, long story short I don't have a copy (that I can find yet)of my 2 error only code but if I ever figure out how to post my code on here id show u let me try that again an maybe this will be a little easier for everyone

Comment: Ran my newest revised version in the terminal and got output of:        sh slimmerdirty.sh
slimmerdirty.sh: 144: slimmerdirty.sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution.

Comment: Ran same revised code through shellcheck.net output of:
$ shellcheck myscript
 Line 22:}
^-- SC1089: Parsing stopped here. Is this keyword correctly matched up? Line 138:
if [ `whoami` == "root" ]; then
  ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this backtick expansion. Fix to allow more checks.
   ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this backtick expansion. Line 143:
^-- SC1072: Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
I'm sorry for the multiple comments I'm new to computers in this type of use I can't figure out how to properly paste my code to help aid in this predicament of mine.